# File search tool

Tags: windows-7, file-search

I need a tool in which I can **import a list of file names**, from the clipboard or a text file, and then do a **keyword search** across a drive or a folder and its sub-folders.
I have hundreds of texture replacers, named incorrectly and placed in several folders with incorrect folder structure, so my goal is to find their duplicates (which I want to replace) in another folder with a proper folder structure and proper names, so I can rename the incorrectly named ones.
Something like this:
D:\folder 1\folder 2\1flower%%.dds
D:\folder 1\stone0000.dds
D:\folder 1\folder 2\folder 3\vindovinterior.dds
- All named incorrectly and placed in incorrect folder structure.
Search for a keyword - flower, stone and interior in C:\Program Files\Some Game and find (i.e)
C:\Program Files\Some Game\flowerkitchen.dds
C:\Program Files\Some Game\stoneHD.dds
C:\Program Files\Some Game\windowinterior.dds

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for some [python](https://www.python.org/) scripting but I would strongly recommend backing up the original folder structures first.

The modules & functions to pay especial attention to are [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob), [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) & [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

### For the Beginner

If you are unfamiliar with python and possibly other scripting languages I would suggest spending a little time reading a good book on the subject. In this case I would specifically recommend [Automate The Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) by Al Sweigart there is even an example in [Chapter 9](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter9/) that shows how to do the following:

*quote*

- Making copies of all PDF files (and only the PDF files) in every sub-folder of a folder
- Removing the leading zeros in the filenames for every file in a folder of hundreds of files named spam001.txt, spam002.txt, spam003.txt, and so on
- Compressing the contents of several folders into one ZIP file (which could be a simple backup system)

*end quote*

Where the first two are similar enough to your problem to give you a great starting point *but if you have not done any programming or scripting it would be a great idea to read the first couple of chapters before going on to that one*.

**Note:** Automate the Boring Stuff with Python is Free to read under a [Creative Commons license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/). There are also purchasable copies of the book and a Udemy Online Video Course ***Hint:*** *Read the introduction of the online book before buying anything there may be discounts available.*

**Disclaimer:** I have no financial interest in the above book or course I just think that this is a great book to recommend for a beginner.

### *Warning*

*Python, while completely free, is highly addictive - once you start using it you may **never** be able to stop!*

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but unfortunately I know nothing about python or scripting in general. I'd prefer an automated solution with a gui for this type of work, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @karlosmunjos - what you are trying to do is a very specialised type of operation that needs someone to step back and think about the rules for which file needs renaming, how to rename it, etc. - however it is not an uncommon need and __very__ easy to do in languages like python. This is probably why you are unlikely to find a GUI for it. Expanding the answer with a little more help.

Comment: Now that book looks really interesting, I'll be sure to check it out. Once again, thanks for the useful info.

Answer (score 1):

A duplicate finder like [this one](https://www.easyduplicatefinder.com)  should be  able to find any duplicates. Usually it is not easy, when used the first time, but sooner or later tools like that come in handy in many situations, so it will be time well spent. You should be able to achieve results in minutes, a first time programmer on the other hand, might take weeks to get there.